# Bidirectional Hyper Backup between local and remote synology NAS

Tags: networking, vpn, backup, nas, synology-diskstation

I'm trying to set up a system where my friend and I back up each other's files on our respective Synology NAS's. I followed [this guide](https://www.wundertech.net/how-to-backup-a-synology-nas-to-a-remote-synology-nas) to set up a Hyper Backup task from a local Synology NAS to a remote NAS. It works! The steps I followed:

- Install Hyper Backup on the local NAS and Hyper Backup Server on the remote NAS
- [Set up a hostname](https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/connection_ddns?version=7) for my local NAS IP address using DDNS
- [Set up a VPN server](https://www.wundertech.net/synology-nas-openvpn-server-setup-configuration/) on local NAS (I used the "VPN Server" DSM application)
- [Configure a static IP](https://www.wundertech.net/setup-a-static-ip-address-for-openvpn-clients-on-your-synology-nas/) address (on the local VPN Server) for the remote NAS
- [Connect to](https://www.wundertech.net/how-to-create-an-openvpn-network-interface-on-a-synology-nas) the (local) VPN Server from the remote NAS
- Create a Hyper Backup task on the local NAS, connecting to the static IP that I set up for the remote NAS

This all worked and I was able to successfully back up local files to the remote NAS.

Then, I tried to create a Hyper Backup task in the other direction - from the remote NAS to the local NAS, and I wasn't sure what IP address to use. I tried 10.8.0.1, which is the default IP address shown in the VPN Server application:

[image]

But I got the following message:

[image: error message]

I also tried connecting to the VPN Server from the local NAS itself so I could be assigned a static IP, but got this error:
[image]

How do I set up a task in the other direction? What destination IP address should I use for Hyper Backup from the remote NAS? Or do I need to set up a separate VPN Server on the remote NAS?

#### Edit:

Providing more information about setup of static IP:

Following [this guide](https://www.wundertech.net/setup-a-static-ip-address-for-openvpn-clients-on-your-synology-nas/), I ssh'd into the local NAS and ran the following commands:

#### Tell VPNCenter where to look for user IP addresses

```
cd /usr/syno/etc/packages/VPNCenter/
sudo mkdir userIPs
vim openvpn/openvpn.conf
# add this line to the file:
client-config-dir usr/syno/etc/packages/VPNCenter/userIPs/
# end entry to file
```

#### Add static IP for a user

```
vim /usr/syno/etc/packages/VPNCenter/userIPs/user_name
# add this line to the file
ifconfig-push 10.5.0.10 10.5.0.9
# end entry to file
```

This is how I set a static IP for the remote machine; I'm not sure how to set a static IP for the local machine running the VPN server.

Comment: 10.8.0.1 doesn’t exist on your intranet network.  If it’s a VPN intranet, you need to provide a route, on both ends to that subnet. Provide those routes to us by editing your question

Comment: I'm still new at this, so I'm not sure what you mean. Is the VPN intranet the subnet you are talking about? Also, what do you mean by "provide a route on both ends"? If you have a link where I could learn more I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You had to define a route to each machine so they can see each other  Provide us that information.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "define a route", but I just added info about how I set up a static IP for the remote machine, if that is what you mean? I'm not sure how to set a static IP for the machine where the VPN server is running.

Comment: If this is not what you are looking for, could you give an example of the information you are looking for?

Comment: If you are talking about the public hostname I put in the VPN config file, it is XXX.synology.me. That is how the remote machine is able to find the local machine when connecting to the VPN